# I've been coding with notepad++ and now I'm getting into Eclipse IDE and I'm having trouble with my older projects

Tags: java, eclipse, notepad++

So, 
I have been coding Java last semester (college) and we've always done it in Notepad++ , compile and execute by CMD (very simple programs though) and now I want to start codding in Eclipse, since I heard that it saves you a lot of time in syntax and gives you a heads up on typos and errors (Also I'm tired of compiling and executing by console). But the thing is that I usually have my code into two folders (model and interface) and use the

```
package modelo;
package interfaz;
```

And now I execute eclipse and open these files, but it doesn't seem to work, I mean the code shows up and I can edit, but it wont show help or even let me execute the code. I know it must be a very noobie question but I can't seem to make it work.

Update:
[This is what i get when i import my "project"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Ox1.png)
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOBi3.png)

Comment: Are there any error messages?  Can you show us your file structure?  What settings have you set in eclipse?  How did you import your project?

Comment: There are a lot of information in the internet on how to set-up your eclipse workspace, please do that first and if you have specific question then you can ask it here.

Comment: did you explicitly make model and interfaz packages?

Comment: Yeah, i made two folders, with the names model and interfaz, there i created the .java archives

Comment: the folder icon for a package is decorated. use file|new|package and make a new package say foo. see how it is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is **not** configured as **Java project**:

1. Create a Java project via ***File > Other...: Java > Java Project***
2. **Copy** the content of the **`src`** folder into the `src` folder of the new project
3. In the new project, **open the class that contains the main method** and click the ***Run*** button

Answer (score 0):

maybe eclipse didn't figure out which `main` you want to run.

try right click on `Menu.java` -> `run as` -> `1 Java Application`

Comment: I only have that main. I click run as and it says none aplicable

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a project in Eclipse first, then add packages and classes in that project, make sure that the JDK in classpath is configured correctly